# Problems using pip installer

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables

I'm trying to import matplotlib in my python file. I have already tried both pip install and pip3.9 install however this (see picture) doesn't seem to help.
[image]

I have also added the paths to the PATH enviroment variable however this doesn't seem to fix the problem either.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem because all the posts I have seen al just talk about the PATH enviroment variable but even after adding the paths to the folders where pip installed matplotlib my problem didn't go away.

Comment: 1. They are the same image. 2. What happens when you open a command prompt and type in `python` and enter? Did pip install and pip3.9 install have different results in the command prompt? Did they do the same thing?

Comment: 3. Do you see pip.exe file in any of those paths that you’ve added when you open them in file explorer?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install --user matplotlib`

Comment: I seem to have fixed the problem by installing anaconda.